# How to get duration (HH:MM:SS) from AVAudioPlayer in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, duration

durCurrently i am working in iPhone application, Using `AVAudioPlayer` to play the audio file in my application, then get the duration value from `AVAudioPlayer`.

I get the duration value like : 252.765442.

but i want `HH/MM/SS 02:52:76`.

How to convert this, Please help me

Thanks in Advance..

I tried this:

```
audioPlayer =  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath] error:&err];
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    float duration = (float)audioPlayer.duration;
    NSLog(@"duration:%f",duration);
```

Comment: Now thats called Spoon Feeding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = audioPlayer.duration;
 // Get the system calendar
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Create the NSDates
NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:date1];
// Get conversion to hours, minutes, seconds
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *breakdownInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];
NSLog(@"%02d:%02d:%02d", [breakdownInfo hour], [breakdownInfo minute], [breakdownInfo second]);
[date1 release];
[date2 release];
```

Comment: Duration 252.765442, then i tried you way but getting like  string:05:34:12, its wrong

Comment: @Minu, You might have to convert to milliseconds. Let me check.

Comment: i want hour and minute from seconds (audioPlayer.duration).

Comment: Not a problem. If you want to do in objective c way, you can use this.

Comment: @Minu, Saw some of the comments here. I dont understand what is going on here. If you feel that mine is correct answer(your question was to get it in 02:52:76 format and I can see that only in my answer it is there in that format) and especially after I had the correct answer, you didnt have to worry about selecting mine as the correct answer. Anyways it is upto you to decide the usefulness of an answer.

Comment: I can see that someone has downvoted. What's wrong with the answer? Please post it as comment if you feel like the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 8):

#### You can also try,

```
    // Say you get the duration from AVAudioPlayer *p;
    NSString *dur = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", (int)((int)(p.duration)) / 60, (int)((int)(p.duration)) % 60];
```

#### As @ Victor John commented, In Swift,

```
    String(format: "%02d:%02d", ((Int)((audioPlayer?.currentTime)!)) / 60, ((Int)((audioPlayer?.currentTime)!)) % 60)
```

Comment: A much simpler approach yet very effective for minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's so simple and effective.  Its code in Swift like this  `String(format: "%02d:%02d", ((Int)((audioPlayer?.currentTime)!)) / 60, ((Int)((audioPlayer?.currentTime)!)) % 60)`